# How to determine which customer bought the items based on price

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6

I have two tables called `transdt` and `inv_sldtl`.

The `transdt` table consists of the customer ID and the total price of the items that customers bought.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
| BranchID | TransCode | ControlNo | CustomerID |    Date    | Amount   |
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
|        1 |        48 |       469 |       1170 | 2017-05-01 | 295.00   |
|        1 |        48 |       469 |       1185 | 2017-05-01 | 44257.24 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
```

and the `inv_sldtl` contains the item id, unit cost, quantity and total cost.

```
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| BranchID | TransCode | ItemID | ControlNo |    Date    | Quantity | UnitCost | TotalCost |
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
|        1 |        48 |    108 |       469 | 2017-05-01 | 1.00     | 45.00    | 45.00     |
|        1 |        48 |    736 |       469 | 2017-05-01 | 10.00    | 25.00    | 250.00    |
|        1 |        48 |    622 |       469 | 2017-05-01 | 4.00     | 280      | 1120.00   |
|        1 |        48 |    500 |       469 | 2017-05-01 | 4.00     | 10784.31 | 43137.24  |
|          |           |        |           |            |          |          |           |
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Given that the results of two tables are in same one transaction which is determined by the `ControlNo`. 
Is there any way we can output like this?

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
| ControlNo | TransCode | CustomerID | ItemID |    Date    |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
|       469 |        48 |       1170 |    108 | 2017-05-01 |
|       469 |        48 |       1170 |    736 | 2017-05-01 |
|       469 |        48 |       1185 |    622 | 2017-05-01 |
|       469 |        48 |       1185 |    500 | 2017-05-01 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
```

I assume that we can determine it based on the `Amount` in `transdt` table and `TotalCost` in `inv_sldtl` table. But how?
**EDIT:** Since SQL seems doesn't have a solution for this, How can I achieve this using VB6 as my programming language as what @ThorstenKettner have told?

Thanks :)

Comment: It is not clear how to join the tables.

Comment: The design of the tables is flawed. The `transdt` should have a `PK`, that would become the `FK` in the `inv_sldtl` to make it easier to join these tables.

Comment: Please provide more details in question, that what output you wants, and what already you have done ?

Comment: It seems the table design is inappropriate. You store the customers involved in a transaction; you store the items bought in a transaction; but you don't store which item was bought by which customer. Now you want to find this out by comparing customer totals with item totals, hoping for an unambiguous solution. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes. you're correct.

Comment: You seem to be in the process of re-writing your tables, so as to get normalized tables `transaction(transcode, branchid, controlno, date)` and `transaction_detail(transcode, customerid, itemid, quantity, unitcost, totalcost)`. I suppose there are only few transactions in the table, yet. You have started with this table design and (hopefully) immediately found that it was incomplete. Now you want to get it straight. If this is the case and if you are not that much of an experienced programmer, you may want to do the customer/item match manually rather than write a complicated program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to build all item combinations in order to compare these with the customers' totals.

```
pack #1    | pack #2    | sums
-----------+------------+-----------------
item 1     | item 2+3+4 | 45.00 , 44507.24
item 1+2   | item 3+4   | ...
item 1+3   | item 2+4   | ...
item 1+4   | item 2+3   | ...
item 1+2+3 | item 4     | ...
item 2     | item 1+3+4 | ...
item 2+3   | item 1+4   | ...
...
```

This is no task for SQL. At least not for a DBMS that doesn't support recursive queries. So use a programming language instead. I.e. use Java, C#, whatever, read the data, then get your totals by calling a recursive function.

**UPDATE:** You have asked for further help on the algorithm. Here is one possible way:

1. You have a set of n customers, here (1170,1185).
2. You have a set of m items, here (108,500,622,736).
3. Take the customer with the lowest total, here customer 1170 with 295.00.
4. Find item combinations matching the price. You'd use a recursive function call and stop as soon as the price is too high. So you quickly end up with item 108 = 45.00, item 736 = 250.00 and items 108+736 = 295.00. Only the last combination is a match.
5. Remove the customer from the cusomer set. Remove the item(s) from the item set.
6. Continue with step 3, till you are done.

To make this a tad more complicated: You see that you can have multiple matches for a customer, e.g. both items A + B and items B + C + D match the customer total. So step 5 and following must be done for every match. Another recursion :-)

Do this slowly, step by step, so as not to get confused. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you want and if you have Primary or Foreign keys which if you don't should have your ControlNo in first table transdt the PK and FK in your inv_sldt1 so that you can use something like my code below. This way you can also link the tables together by some column. Anyways again without seeing everything here is what I came up with on the fly check it out and let me know.

```
SELECT CustomerID, Date, Quantity 
FROM transdt
INNER JOIN inv_sldt1 ON transdt.ControlNo=inv_sldt1.ControlNo
WHERE ItemID = 108
```